# ubuntu 13.04 unable to locate package ubuntu after installing ubuntu sdk

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

Am new to ubuntu and software development but after installing the sdk via the terminal, it say "unable to locate package ubuntu"
then "unable to locate package sdk"

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I think you mean that you're trying to install the Ubuntu SDK, but you're not able to.</sub>

The correct name of the Ubuntu SDK package is `ubuntu-sdk`. So, to install the Ubuntu SDK package, the correct command is this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

---

#### Explanation of the error you got:

What you probably did in the terminal is this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu sdk
```

This means: install a package called `ubuntu` and a package called `sdk`. You put a space between the names, this indicates that you want to install two packages called `ubuntu` and `sdk`, but since there are no packages called that, you got the error `unable to locate <package>`.

You can search for the package names before you try to install. For example, you can use this command: `apt-cache search ubuntu sdk`, here's the output:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ apt-cache search ubuntu sdk
ubuntu-sdk - Ubuntu SDK
alaa@aa-lu:~$
```

This indicates that the package name is `ubuntu-sdk`, and that's what you use when you try to install.